# Data frame of repeated values

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm currently working with R. I have a data frame with three names, one per column: `year1`, `year2` and `year3`. Each column has a set of numeric data.

I want to have a resulting data frame which includes the data that is repeated in two different columns, that is: if `num.4` is repeated in `year1` and `year2` the new data frame has `num.4`, in the same way, if `num.5` is repeated in `year2` and `year3` the new data frame has `num.5` included.

I tried the following code:

```
newdf1 <- origdf[origdf$year1 == origdf$year2 | origdf$year1 == origdf$year3, c(1)]

newdf2 <- origdf[origdf$year2 == origdf$year3, c(2)]
```

and then I merged both data frames, but not all the data was included, it contained many `NA` values.

Then I tried the following code:

```
newdf <- origdf[origdf$year1 == origdf$year2 | origdf$year1 == origdf$year3 & origdf$year2 == origdf$year3, c(1, 2)]
```

But it also didn't work, it gave me a resulting data frame with many NA values and some correct values, but not all of the repeated numbers were included.

How can I effectively have a data frame that includes values that are repeated in exactly two of the three different columns of the original data frame, without repeated values (I don't want to have a number that is repeated in all the three columns of the original data frame)?

The expected outcome would be:

```
>newdf

1 num.4
2 num.5
```

Comment: Please give the expected result in your example. Thanks.

Comment: Also do not show images as no one else can use the data except by retyping it all.  Show output of `dput(x)` where `x` is the input.

Comment: I already edited the question, is it more precise? Thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand in proper way, you are looking for intersections between the columns of your data frame, but elements which are **common for all** three columns should be **excluded**. Then `intersect()` function may be a solution. The code may look like that

```
n_years <- 3
# generate all possible combinations of two indices of considered years
indices_comb <- combn(x = 1:n_years, m = 2)
# apply intersect() along all possible combinations
all_intersects <- sapply(function(i) intersect(origdf[, indices_comb[1, i]], 
    origdf[, indices_comb[2, i]]), X = 1:ncol(indices_comb))
```

Finely, exclude the elements which are common for **all** original columns (`year1`, `year2`, `year3`):

```
# find elements which are common for all pairwise intersections
in_all <- Reduce(intersect, all_intersects)
# combine all pairwise intersections into one vector
in_pairw <- Reduce(all_intersects, f = c)
# exclude the elements which are common for all intersections
newdf <- data.frame(res = setdiff(in_pairw, in_all))
```

The above solution may be easily scaled for an arbitrary number of original columns (years). But note, please, that only unique combinations are returned. That is, `num.4`  appears two times in both `year1` and `year2`, only one `num.4` will be returned.